# python regex include end-of-line char in capture group or not?

Tags: python, regex

When doing a search within a line that includes the end of the line should one include the $ into the capture group or not?

Example included:

```
x=re.search("\S+(bla\S+bla$)",line)
```

Example excluded:

```
x=re.search("\S+(bla\S+bla)$",line)
```

Are there significant advantages / risks of one over the other?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$` ending anchor is zero-width, meaning that even if you do capture it, it won't contribute anything to the capture group.  So, I might actually consider the first version to be an anti-pattern, and would therefore always use the second version:

```py
x = re.search("\S+(bla\S+bla)$", line)
```

In both cases, the underlying pattern is the same, so I would expect the regex engine to take the same steps, and have the same performance.